# Appending a null value when max() is empty

Tags: python, opencv, max

The code below finds a contour based on its maximum area but when there is no contour to be found I want to append `0` to a list in order to work around the `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` error but it fails. Why is that?

```
contours = cv2.findContours(binaryimage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if len(contours) == 2:
        contours = contours[0]
    else:
        contours = contours[1]
maxcontour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)   #filter maximum contour based on contour area 
if len(maxcontour) == 0:
    areavalue.append(0)

maxarea = cv2.contourArea(maxcontour)
areavalue.append(maxarea)
```

Edit: Upon addition of the `default = 0` I get an error for `maxarea`

```
maxcontour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, default = 0)   #filter maximum contour based on contour area 
maxarea = cv2.contourArea(maxcontour)
areavalue.append(maxarea)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Python3.8 (it may be earlier), you can write

```
max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, default=0)
```

where `default` says what to return when the list is empty.

Comment: It seems to give me an error when I do this. The cause of the error comes from the fact I use ```maxcontour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, default =0)``` for ```maxarea = cv2.contourArea(maxcontour)```. I have edited my code in the question to accommodate this.

Comment: Oh.  You need to make your "default=" be something reasonable for the situation.  You either need to return some contour that has zero area, or you need `default=None`, and then test the `None` case before taking the area.  The point is that `default=` gets rid of the error message from `max` in the empty case.

Comment: Or of course, just test whether `contours` is empty (`if contours:`) before even calling `max`.  Whatever makes the most sense for your code.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes so much sense. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: When setting ```default = None``` I get this error ```ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```